# What is the shape of cost function of weighted graph matching problem?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

According to Umeyama, the weighted graph matching problem can be formulated as

$min_P || PA_GP^T - A_H ||$

s.t. $P$ is a permutation matrix.

where $A_G$ and $A_H$ are n-by-n matrices

If we relax $P$ to be doubly stochastic matrix, how will the cost function looks like?

Concave? Non-convex with multiple local minimums? Or any other shape?

Comment: Could you maybe explain how this formulation works?

Comment: @usul Sure no problem.
Consider two networks with adjacency matrix $A_G$ and $A_H$
$||A_G-B_H||_F$ is the network distance of the two networks under the mapping: node $i$ in network $A_G$ maps to node $i$ in network $A_H$ for all $i$.

Since $P$ is a permutation matrix, minimizing over $P$ means that consider all the possible permutation/mapping, select the one that can produce the shortest network distance.

Comment: OK, thanks. And what is network distance? (Googling didn't help me much, haha.)

Comment: @usul It is a distance metric to quantify how "dissimilar" the two networks are.

Comment: Sure, but I mean how is it calculated?

Comment: @usul In this case the frobenius norm of the difference of two adjacency matrix is used.